# XMPP - Retrieve last n messages from chat room

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

Anyone know if there is a way to query the last n messages in a muc in xmpp (specifically ejabberd) without joining the room.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, not without modifications to the server software.

If you do actually join, you can specify the amount of history you want with the `<history/>` element, see [Managing Discussion History in XEP 45](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-managehistory).

Answer (score 0):

Messages are kept in each chat room process memory.
You will have to modify the code to expose access to that data structure programmatically.